# HTML/CSS. Вертикальное перекрытие блоков

Tags: html, css

На странице есть блок `.footer`, приатаченный к низу. На широких экранах футер и предыдущий блок совпадают ровно по границам, когда высота футера - минимально-заданная классом. Но когда при масштабировании страницы футер увеличивает высоту, то закрывает часть предыдущего блока на дельту от текущей своей высоты и заданного минимума в классе `.footer`.

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 3em;
}
```

Блок перед футером имеет стилизацию по умолчанию от браузера.

Подскажите как можно убрать это перекрытие?

Comment: Немного не понимаю, что у вас написано. 
Смоделируйте ситуацию на jsfiddle.net и пришлите сюда.

Comment: Решил вопрос компенсацией вертикального перекрытия блоков JavaScript-регулировкой высоты нижних внутренних отступов padding-bottom перекрытого блока в зависимости от высоты футера при изменении ширины экрана.